# What is the ruling about marriage if wife calls her husband her brother or has bad thoughts that she herself must be a disbeliever?

Tags: sharia

Salam. Once I was talking to my friend about my husband and she called him Ali bhai (brother), so I misspoke the same word. Then I read somewhere that mistakenly **calling your husband your brother** doesn't **void your marriage**, rather its by comparing them together. Now I get these **whispering from Satan** (Bad thoughts) regarding how my husband looks similar to my brother and his back is like my brother etc. I haven't said it to his face but I just keep thinking these bad thoughts.

Whenever I realize that I am having these thoughts, **I say 'AstagfirULLAH'** (May ALLAH azawajal forgive me). I read somewhere **calling your yourself a disbeliever also nullifies your marriage**, now I get **whispering** about these thoughts as well. I don't speak any of such whispering but I keep thinking about them that I may be a disbeliever but then I say the 'Shahada' again and then I think that since **I became a disbeliever, my marriage must have nullified**. I love my husband a lot, hence I am very conscious of all these things.

Please let me know if my marriage has nullified or not?

Comment: Well in my opinion you do overrate or exaggerate some strange and bad  thoughts and you should in first place fight your whispering because it would harm your marriage more then anything else.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a woman cannot give her husband a divorce. Even if she says it clearly with all the intention from the bottom of her heart. The only time a woman can give her husband a divorce is if the husband gives her the right to do so. However, she can ask for **Khula'**, which is an anullment of the marriage contract that's granted to the woman in a court of Islamic law.

Now when it comes to divorce, it's all about intention. If your husband gave you the right and you had the option to use that right, you'd have two ways to divorce your husband (which is clearly not the case in this case):

1. Clear or Sareeh divorce. That means you use the word Talaq in a way that has a meaning. Like, I am giving you talaq. I am divorcing you. I've divorced you, etc.
2. Kenaya divorce is the type of divorce where a person uses ambiguous wording that could mean a divorce or something else. Now in this case a divorce takes place only if the person had the intention.

So sister, don't worry. You are FINE. Whispering is from the Shaytan. Try to recite Surat Al Falaq, Surat Al Naas and Surat Al Fatiha regularly. Make sure you do your prayers on time and all these thoughts will go away InshaAllah.

Disclaimer: I am not a scholar nor an Alim. I am posting this answer based on my understanding as a fellow muslim who happens to have attended a few lectures on Talaq.